# Do type conversions slow program running?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Th title is quite obvious.
In my case, and for the sake of simplicity, I avoid using, for instance, unsigned int instead of int, as it makes coding faster and simpler.
(BTW, Im using an Android IDE, CppDroid)

Yet, the IDE frequently alerts me to implicit conversions at, for example, For loops where the incremented variable (int) is compared with the size of a vector (size_t/unsigned int).

My questions are:
Do type conversions take time?
If so, how long do they take compared to other common operations?
In the case convertions do take some time, is it worth to correctly define variables in order to avoid convertions?

Comment: It is not about performance. Everytime your compiler warns you about comparison of int vs size_t or unsigned int, you have a ticking bomb in your code.

Comment: The question is what is involved in the type conversion and what kind of data along with the processor type and characteristics as well as memory and memory bus characteristics. And it also depends on the compiler and the code the compiler emits.

Comment: How does changing `unsigned` to `int` make coding faster?  Do you need to take a keyboarding class?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ... aside that most modern IDE's support type completion.

Comment: Either that, or just make sure your codebase has a `uint` or `uint32` typedef. There's no excuses for lazyness at the cost of correctness.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is valid, although the goal is misconstrued. It is paramount to *correctly define variables*, but not because of mysterious performance.

It is to ensure correctness. Comparing unsigned integer with signed one is a ticking bomb, as well as (most usually) comparing `size_t` with integer.

For example, consider following snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) { }
```

For all you know, this code can lead to undefined behavior! If the size of the vector is bigger than maximum size signed integer can hold (which is usually the case with 64bit systems) your integer will be overflowing, which is undefined. Compiler might just remove the loop altogether, if it can proove that size of the vector is bigger than maximum int!

Similar looking (and incorrecet as well) line

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(), ++i) { }
```

Is not going to cause undefined behaviour, but it will hang the program when vector size is greater than maximum int. No good thing either.

And of course, the correct way of doing this is

```
for (decltype(vec.size()) i = 0; i < vec.size(), ++i) { }
```

Comment: Should'nt `vec.size(), ++i` be `vec.size(); ++i`?

Comment: @GillBates, certainly. Thans for spotting it.

Comment: To be pedantic, `vec.size()` is not guaranteed to be `unsigned int`. You should use `std::vector<T>::size_type` instead.

Comment: @user6412786, and where did I ever say it is guaranteed to be?? (most likely, it will not) My example is about **wrong** code!

Comment: @SergeyA If `v.size()` is `unsigned long` you have a problem.

Comment: @user6412786, what are you talking about? I do not see your point.

Comment: @user6412786 They never said it was the case. And why couldn't it be? Isn't it the case on 32 bits platforms?

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you convert to what.

That particular warning of signed/unsigned mismatch results in zero overhead, but you may end treating negative number as huge unsigned one (or other way around) - so as long as you are using `int`, and you don't expect to break into 2^31 numbers land, you are safe.

As safe, as people writing file I/O routines around 1990 (never expecting to see 3GiB file in their life). ...not very funny nowadays (still so much SW is broken on 2+GiB file size).

---

Some other conversions like from `int` to `uint_8` may have tiny overhead, so it's better to avoid them - if possible (by designing the code to use the desired data type all around).

I would firstly address clarity and functionality of the code, and that usually leads to usage of particular data type for particular value all the time, without any conversion.

After the code works, you can measure the performance and consider what optimization makes sense (including usage of mismatched data types with conversions between them).

---

conclusion: just fix it, use proper data type.

Comment: Yep, nothing like getting a negative number returned as an error code and then turning it into a huge whopping character copy length which is an unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

Type conversions *might* give performance hits (when signedness, bitness or conversion between floating-point types are involved), but, as a general rule, the type identity of the many things in a program is merely a conceptual language front-end feature. When such hits *do* happen, however, it is because the types involved mean reasonably different things, and hence code must be emitted in order to properly solve the conversion.

Another thing which is completely different from the above is the invocation of type conversion operators in C++, which can run arbitrary code and, thus, most obviously influence in the final program behavior (not only performance).

As mentioned by others, correct use of the type system is most important for program correctness, at least or specially in languages such as C and C++. Using mismatched types can affect the program behavior in some corner cases, albeit can have no impact whatsoever on the execution time otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends.**

Actually converting the data between types will require extra calculations. That much should probably be obvious. Usually those calculations take extra time, so they will have a performance impact. However, there are several factors that mitigate the actual impact of this:

1. The compiler can optimize types in some cases to minimize conversions.
2. Some platforms implement certain conversions in hardware.

The primary concern surrounding calculations with unlike types typically has much less to do with performance and more to do with safety and producing expected results. That is why the compiler is warning you; the vast majority of compilers will not tell you that you are doing something inefficient, but they will tell you that you are doing something dangerous.

For example, comparing an `int` with an `unsigned int` is asking for trouble. The `int` has a negative range, the `unsigned int` has a larger positive range. On conversion to `unsigned int`, the negative range of the `int` will appear to be larger than its own positive range. It is very easy to generate endless loops or out-of-bounds errors with such a construct.

You should normally only worry yourself about type conversion performance if you are dealing with huge amounts of data - like large vectors/arrays that need converted between formats. You would have to loop over the data in some way, so it would be a conscious action. For example, converting a 10000 element vector of `char`s to `int`s. In these cases, you might need to consider if you have a design flaw that is requiring needless conversion of data.

It is worth pointing out that in the above example, even if the conversion itself were instant, the iteration and copy is not.

As for an example of platforms where this can be done to an extent in hardware, most video cards are able to interpret integers as floats on a normalized range, of the sort `255` --> `1.0`. However, many other conversions, like conversions between image formats, are still done in software.

Given the platform and optimization details vary greatly, answering how long a given conversion takes relative to other operations is effectively impossible. If you are dealing with enough data that a conversion is creating a noticeable performance bottleneck, then profile that conversion.

---

It is worth it to make sure your types match to the best of your ability if you are dealing with enough data for it to matter; that is a subjective measurement of value, though, and will depend on what you are doing.

It is **always worth it** to make sure implicit type conversions do not cause errors, as errors due to them can be some of the worst possible in C/C++ (memory leaks, buffer overflows, access violations, etc.).